# Auto id for select statements in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to create / to have an auto id column in the select statements in Oracle.

Example:
Assume we have a table ITEMS without an id

Normal select-statement

```
Select name
from ITEMS
```

What I'm looking for is something like this

```
select AutoIdGen(), name
from ITEMS
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ROWID` or `ROWNUM` in oracle ,like this:

```
SELECT ROWID,ROWNUM,name from ITEMS;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `row_number` for this. The `row_number` analytical function works a little different then `rownum`. You can also apply partitioning on the results when you want to or sort on different columns then the results.

```
select row_number() over (order by name)
,      name
from   ITEMS
```